# Joomla sending Data (special Image) with Ajax (Formdata)

Tags: ajax, file, joomla, upload

Using Joomla:
My problem is when I submit the button, ajax send an empty data array back to my client. Debbuging in the console shows me that datas in the header but the preview and response values are empty.

Here is my code (I am using a modal form from bootstrap).

HTML in my default script:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_addproduct&view=addproducts'); ?>" method="post" name="modalMessageForm" id="modalMessageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="message-image-upload" accept="image/*" style="display:none;" name="message-image-upload">
<textarea class="form-control message-textarea" id="message-textarea" placeholder="Nachricht..." name="new-message" rows="4"></textarea> 
<button type="button" id="button-close-message" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-message-close" style="display:none; margin-top:5px;"><?=JText::_( 'COM_ADDPRODUCT_MODAL_MESSAGES_CLOSE')?></button>            
</form>
```

JQuery / Ajax:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#modalMessageForm", function(e)
        {
            var form = $('#modalMessageForm').get(0); 
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData    = new FormData(form);

for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
                console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
            }

$.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php?option=com_addproduct&task=sendMessages&format=json",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                processData: false    
            })      
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
console.log('Message: '+data.new-message+' PicName: '+data.img);
            })  

        });
```

Here my controller.php:

```
public function sendMessages()
        {
            JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true);
            $app        = JFactory::getApplication();
            $input      = $app->input;
            $new-message = $input->getString('new-message', '', 'RAW');
            $img        = $_FILES['message-image-upload']["name"];
            $img    = JFile::makeSafe($img);

            $results=array(
                'new-message' => 'new-message',
                'img' => $img
                        ); 

            echo json_encode($results);
            $app->close();
        }
```

I got the datas / variables in the console log.

it is: 
new-message: null,
img: null

trying to set contentType: false will give me an 500 error.

Thank you very much

That´s the info from my network
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhnC4.jpg)

Comment: form.append("message-image-upload", $("#message-image-upload")[0].files[0]);  this is for get file data

Comment: I figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

I figure something out. 
It´s the URL in my ajax command. 
When I am using a normal url like

```
url: 'upload.php'
```

that will work and then I can set the

```
contentType: false,
```

But this is not safety enought.
I just want to use this url

```
url: "index.php?option=com_addproduct&task=sendMessages&format=json",
```

But then I got the error message that the view is not found. That´s very strange.

Comment: ok, I got the solution. I am using an external file (upload.php) and include the joomla framework.